# Incremento em lista Python

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou criando um script para fazer logins automáticos em equipamentos. Criei uma lista com vários IPs que são os equipamentos que desejo acessar. Quero criar um loop, tentei com while e for, mas não consegui.

Cada volta no laço ele deve executar os comandos para acessá-los, porém não estou conseguindo incrementar a posição da lista, para que na volta seguinte, o IP da próxima posição seja chamado.

```
lista = ['11.111.111.111','22.222.222.222','3.333.333.333']
ip = lista[0]
while lista != 44.444.444.44:
    username = raw_input("Username:")
    password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
```

Podem me ajudar?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você só quer incrementar (meu chará) é muito simples. Utilize o famoso `for`:

```
lista = ['11.111.111.111','22.222.222.222','3.333.333.333']
for ip in lista:
    # faz suas operações com a variável ip
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
    # ... demais operações
```

A váriável `ip` vai atualizar seu valor iterando os elementos da lista.

Comment: Muito obrigado chará, tanto pela resposta quanto pelas sugestões de edição. Sou novo no site e foi de grande ajuda, obrigado!

Comment: Que isso amigo, de nada! :)

Answer (score 0):

Há vários problemas com este código. Considero que talvez você esteja imaginando uma forma de funcionamento do Python que não existe.

A solução envolve iterar sua lista de IPs da seguinte forma:

```
lista = ['11.111.111.111','22.222.222.222','3.333.333.333']

# ip = lista[0] # Isto não precisa

for ip in lista:
    username = raw_input("Username:")   
    password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()     
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())   
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()    
    output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
```

Comment: É isso mesmo Morrison, obrigado pela resposta! Como disse acima, o for - na resposta do Felipe - me ajudou em relação ao problema.